# Redirect the old domain to inner post/page of new domain not affect keyword rankings

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, keyword, ranking

I have an old domain (actually website in wordpress). I want to redirect the main domain (like olddomain.com) to specific inner post/page of new domain, but not affect keyword rankings (like newdomain.com/keyword-abc). Please help. Thanks.

P/S: Is it good to use "URL FORWARDING" to make this work? And it doesn't impact on SEO value of the olddomain? Which option should I use? 1> Temporary Redirect (302 / 307), 2> Permanent Redirect (301)

Answer (score 0):

By some people, it is recommended to use 301 if you want to transfer your ranking. See this [semrush guide](https://www.semrush.com/blog/files/a7d1cf997e2573be93e2b42a7be683c4/) - search for 307. 
Anyway, some time ago, a Google guru told that this doesn't affect their ranking (I couldn't find if this is really true).